# Axios sending 2 or more requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

Look at my simple code:

```
const Test= () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("test").then((data) => {
      console.log(data.data.test);
    }, []);
  });

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </>
  );
};
```

In this example axios send request 2 times - I can see that in network tab and console.log is displaing 2 times. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your react app might be wrapped in StrictMode. If your app is wrapped in strict mode, only in development environment, the components gets rendered twice.